# Change java.util.prefs.Preferences directory

Tags: java, linux, flatpak

I'm currently building a flatpak for a java app but have ran into a small problem with the way it's saving settings. If possible I'd like to solve it without editing the program itself.

It stores settings using java.util.prefs.Preferences like so

```
prefs.put(prefname, val);
```

and this is saved at the default location $HOME/.java/.userPrefs

because I'm bundling openjdk with the app I'd prefer that the preferences weren't saved in the same place that the system install java would store them. I've tried passing these 2 arguments to change the default directory but in both cases the app still writes to $HOME/.java/.userPrefs

```
java -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=$HOME/.var/app/com.test.App/data -jar App.jar
java -Duser.home=$HOME/.var/app/com.test.App/data -jar App.jar
```

I've already tried messing with file permissions and it didn't make a difference

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `FileSystemPreferences.setupUserRoot` and see how its deciding which directory to use. Setting `java.util.prefs.userRoot` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the problem but not sure how to fix it. The program is a launcher for another JAR file. The VM option is applied to the launcher but not the JAR file it downloads and launches. I need the launcher to pass the argument to another jar. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to show the code used to launch the other jar.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with Java Preferences inside a Flatpak app as well and I found out following:

Setting the target directory as a parameter to `java` worked, however only if the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable was not manually set on the user's host. Not sure how likely it is that users set this, but it seems risky that our desired setting will be ignored in that case. Nevertheless here how it worked for me when the variable was not set:

```
java -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=$HOME/.var/app/<yourappid>/config -jar yourapp.jar
```

Potentially better approach - setting it as an environment variable:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=$HOME/.var/app/<yourappid>/config
java -jar yourapp.jar
```

It turned out that this would work more reliably since the user can not override it. Our overriding of `_JAVA_OPTIONS` of course only happens inside our Flatpak environment. The user's env variable remains unchanged.
The approach with the environment variable might also work for your JAR launching another JAR use case

Note: I was using OpenJDK 17 and Flatpak 1.15.6